# Variation of Buffon's Needle Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

What is the probability that a square thrown arbitrarily (with random orientation and position) onto an infinite chessboard, the side of which is equal to the side of the board cell, will not cover any corner of any cell?

I got this solution, I would like you to check it out:

Let's say we have $2$ squares with side $2$ and a common center. The first square is rotated relative to the second by an angle: $\displaystyle-\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$. Then the first square can be shifted vertically and horizontally by no more than: $\displaystyle \Delta(\phi)=\sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}+|\phi|\right)-1$.

Then the required probability is:

$$ P=\frac{2 \int_{0}^{\pi / 4}(2 \Delta(\phi))^{2} d \phi}{2^{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{2(\pi-3)}{\pi}.$$

Also, if I want to calculate when the square covers $2$ points, then I take $\Delta(\phi)=\tan \phi / 2$?

Comment: In your example, if the square is rotated 45 degree, it can shift up by $2-\sqrt{2}$ instead of $\sqrt{2}-1$ according to your formula, maybe there is a small mistake?